# Correct to respond with 200 or 404 in the following scenario?

Tags: rest, http

Lets say I have a URL `/users/{id}/friends` that returns a list of a specific users friends. If the id **does not** exist the response should be `404`, but what about the case that the id **does** exist but **does not** have any friends? Should this be a `200` response with an empty array or `404`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`404 Not Found` would not be appropriate when the `id` exists since it would have a friends list present, it would just potentially be an empty list. It would be more appropriate to send `200 OK` with the actual list even if it is empty, or maybe send `204 No Content` instead if it is actually empty.  It depends on the nature of the request.